# Get RSA Public or Private Key from KeyPair Generation Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, public-key-encryption, pointycastle

I have added pointycastle and generated a keypair, encrypting the trial "Hello World" string. From this, I want to get the values of the Private and Public Key. Is there anywhere they are stored, because whenever I try to print the values of `keyPair.privateKey`, it returns `Instance of 'RSAPrivateKey`.

Here is the code I used

```
        var keyParams = new RSAKeyGeneratorParameters(new BigInt.from(65537), 2048, 5);
        var secureRandom = new FortunaRandom();
        var random = new Random.secure();
        List<int> seeds = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
          seeds.add(random.nextInt(255));
        }
        secureRandom.seed(new KeyParameter(new Uint8List.fromList(seeds)));

        var rngParams = new ParametersWithRandom(keyParams, secureRandom);
        var k = new RSAKeyGenerator();
        k.init(rngParams);
        var keyPair = k.generateKeyPair();
        var cipher = new RSAEngine()..init( true, new PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(keyPair.publicKey));
        print("pubkey: ${keyPair.publicKey.toString()}");
        var cipherText = cipher.process(new Uint8List.fromList("Hello World".codeUnits));
        print("Encrypted: ${new String.fromCharCodes(cipherText)}");
        cipher.init( false, new PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(keyPair.privateKey));
        //cipher.init( false, new PrivateKeyParameter(keyPair.privateKey) )
        var decrypted = cipher.process(cipherText);
        print("Decrypted: ${new String.fromCharCodes(decrypted)}");
```

Comment: Did you try keyPair.privateKey.toString() ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim yes, that returns the same `Instance of RSAPrivateKey`

Comment: This package is poorly documented.I suggest you take a look inside their github code to figure out how to convert `RSAPrivateKey` to a readable form.

Comment: @MazinIbrahim I have tried, but I can't see anything converting it into a readable form. I've tried looking in their Object, as well its generation function, but in there it still shows the same instance output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to import `package:pointycastle/asymmetric/api.dart`, then use:

```
  var k = RSAKeyGenerator()..init(rngParams);
  AsymmetricKeyPair<PublicKey, PrivateKey> keyPair = k.generateKeyPair();
  RSAPrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.privateKey;
  RSAPublicKey publicKey = keyPair.publicKey;
  print(privateKey.d); // prints private exponent
  print(publicKey.n); // prints modulus
```

Recreate from the individual parts:

```
  RSAPrivateKey foo = RSAPrivateKey(
    privateKey.n,
    privateKey.d,
    privateKey.p,
    privateKey.q,
  );
  RSAPublicKey bar = RSAPublicKey(publicKey.n, publicKey.e);
```

Comment: From this, can i recreate a key from just the modulus of public key and exponent of private key?

Comment: Both need the modulus and exponent. The private key also needs `p` and `q`. Check the constructors of `RSAPrivateKey` and `RSAPublicKey`.

Comment: I know you can do that, but from the value of the key, can you make it? (From a single key value?)

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but try it by supplying dummy values instead. (Incidentally, PKCS#1 format includes `p` and `q` so if you're storing your key using that format you'll have those numbers available.)

Comment: also, can I generate a .pem file for this?

Comment: Yes, but you might need to write that yourself using the asn package. It's probably easier to do it the other way round. Generate the key pair elsewhere, save as pem, then parse that in dart and use that to construct the pointy private or public key.

Comment: For generation of a pem and many other useful utils ontop of pointycastle: 

https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#cryptoutils

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found the [`basic_utils` package which has `CryptoUtils`](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#cryptoutils):

> Helper class for cryptographic operations. This is some kind of high level api for pointycastle and asn1lib.

This has many convenience helpers for working with the RSA keys (and others) that can help you work with the key values: e.g.,  `encodeRSA[Public/Private]KeyToPem`.